# How to edit multiple lines when new line is also involved in VIM? (or) <VIM Multiple Line edit Not working>

Tags: linux, vim, vi

I want to edit multiple lines in VIM.I know there exists Visual block editing(i.e CTRL+V ----> I -----> <Make required change> -----> ESC). But Surprisingly it is **not working** for the case of entering a new line.

For example
I want to make the following code

```
if(i==1):
if(i==2):
```

to something like

```
if(i==1):
  print("say Hello")
if(i==2):
  print("say Hello")
```

Hoping for a way to do it without too many commands.
Thanks in advance.
:)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to use `:help .`…

1. Open a new line below the first line and type what you need:

   ```
   o  print("say Hello")
   ```
2. Leave insert mode:

   ```
   <Esc>
   ```
3. Move the cursor down by one line:

   ```
   j
   ```
4. And repeat the last edit:

   ```
   .
   ```

In short:

```
o  print("say Hello")<Esc>j.
```

---

If you absolutely want to use visual mode, here is another way:

1. Select the lines:

   ```
   vj
   ```
2. Press `:` to enter command-line mode, with the range corresponding to the visual selection automatically inserted for you:

   ```
   :'<,'>
   ```
3. Use `:help :s` to substitute the EOL with a newline followed by the desired text on each line in the range:

   ```
   :'<,'>s/$/\r  print("say Hello")<CR>
   ```

Comment: What about using global command? `:g/./normal o    print("say Hello")` or visually selecting and running `:'<,'>g/./normal o   print("say Hello")`?